# Delete from one or two tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
programs         versions
---------        ------------------------
id | name        id | program_id | data
---+-----        ---+------------+-------
1  | One         1  | 1          | OneFoo
2  | Two         2  | 1          | OneBar
                 3  | 2          | TwoBaz
```

`versions.program_id` is a foreign key. When deleting a version, I also want to delete the associated program **only if** the version being deleted was the last one with that program_id. For example, deleting version 1 should not delete any program, but deleting version 3 should also delete program 2.

I am doing this and it works:

```
DELETE FROM versions WHERE id = ?;

DELETE p FROM programs p
WHERE p.id = ?
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM versions v WHERE v.programId = p.id
);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this with just one query? Or by using triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use trigger:

```
delimiter //
create trigger del
AFTER DELETE ON versions FOR EACH ROW
begin
     DELETE FROM programs WHERE  
     programs.id = old.program_id 
     AND 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM versions WHERE versions.program_id = old.program_id);
end
```